# Responding NACK on message in Quarkus reactive code cause the readiness check to fail

Tags: apache-kafka, quarkus, smallrye, smallrye-reactive-messaging, quarkus-reactive

I am implementing a use case where I listen to messages coming from a Kafka topic in a quarkus application in a reactive manner. I followed as base code the `KafkaDeadLetterTopic` class [from this Gist](https://gist.github.com/cescoffier/23ca7b2bcc8c49cee3db29b3f2b59e4a#file-kafkadeadlettertopic-java) included on this blogpost https://quarkus.io/blog/kafka-failure-strategy/

When I alter the code to be reactive and return an Uni like this

```
    @Incoming("movies")
    public Uni<Void> consume1(IncomingKafkaRecord<String, String> movie) {
        return Uni.createFrom().item(movie)
            .onItem()
            .transform(item -> {
                if (movie.getPayload().contains(",")) {
                    throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                        "I don't like movie with , in their title: " + movie);
                }

                return item;
            })
            .onItem().invoke(() -> movie.ack())
            .onFailure().invoke(throwable -> movie.nack(throwable))
            .onItem()
            .ignore().andContinueWithNull();
    }
```

The messages are still being sent to configured Dead Letter Queue, but the health check is marked as unhealthy, making the application to be restarted by the container orchestrator.

[image]

Is this a bug? Am I using incorrectly the Uni on this case? Is the use of case of sending to DLQ from a reactive code supported?

Comment: `.onFailure().invoke(throwable -> movie.nack(throwable))` does not handle the failure. It's still propagated. You need `.onFailure().recoverWithX` to handle the failure and continue the processing.

Answer (score 0):

I tried what [Clement](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1231484/clement) suggest and it works nicely. It seems that I wasn't correctly handling error recovery on Mutiny. This is my final code

```
        @Incoming("movies")
        public Uni<Void> consume1(IncomingKafkaRecord<String, String> movie) {
            return Uni.createFrom().item(movie)
                .onItem()
                .transform(item -> {
                    if (movie.getPayload().contains(",")) {
                        throw new IllegalArgumentException(
                            "I don't like movie with , in their title: " + movie);
                    }

                    return item;
                })
                .onItem().invoke(() -> movie.ack())
                .onItem().ignore().andContinueWithNull()
                .onFailure().recoverWithUni(throwable -> Uni.createFrom().completionStage(movie.nack(throwable)));
        }
```